# C# - How to improve code with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have written a method which simply copies all given properties of a objects to an other with the same type. This method is made because I don't want to manually define the properties to copy when a class has 100+ (hope this never happens, but if...).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the values of the given parameters from source to target
    /// Important Info: Works only with Properties, not with Fields
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The Classtype</typeparam>
    /// <param name="target">The object the values are copied to</param>
    /// <param name="source">The object the values come from</param>
    /// <param name="properties">The Array containing the names of properties which shall be copied</param>
    private static void CopyParams<T>(T target, T source, params string[] properties)
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            target.GetType().GetProperty(property)?.SetValue(target, source.GetType().GetProperty(property)?.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
```

But because this uses reflection inside a loop, this is extremly slow. With 1.000.000 objects and 2 properties, it takes up to 2 seconds. If I do this manually, it takes 36 ms. Is there a way to improve this in performance?

## Edit 1

As some requested the code of the objects, here it is:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void GetValues(TestModel m)
    {
        Name = m.Name;
        Value = m.Value;
    }
}
```

And the code is called like this:

```
    private static void PerformanceTestReflection(int count)
    {
        var models = new List<TestModel>();
        var copies = new List<TestModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            models.Add(new TestModel() { Name = "original", Value = 10 });
            copies.Add(new TestModel() { Name = "copy", Value = 20 });
        }

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            CopyParams(models[i], copies[i], nameof(TestModel.Name), nameof(TestModel.Value));
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Time for Reflection with {count} Models: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms - {sw.ElapsedTicks} ticks");
    }
```

Comment: And first try AutoMapper or tell us why that isn't a solution.

Comment: @bommelding That looks like a good answer (but given that it's a library recommendation, it's better to include usage sample, see [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605))

Comment: Create delegates for the get and set methods, then cache them. Thats probably the same thing automapper does for you.

Comment: @bommelding [performance questions are on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), but yes it's less popular. / Yes.

Comment: @daniel : one thing that does immediately stand out is the GetType() in the _inner_ loop.  Try caching those references.

Comment: You should probably check out Jon Skeet's [MAKING REFLECTION FLY AND EXPLORING DELEGATES](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/).

Comment: If you are not sure that the number of properties is going to be increased to 100s for sure then you are doing unnecessary over engineering.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Because this code will be pasted into a codelibrary, i cannot say if there will be a object with 100 properties anytime anywhere.

Comment: @user202729 also couldn't see the retract option, lol - done.
By the way these comments are way too long, if it's going to continue, the discussion should probably move to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c).

Comment: @user202729 Example code is off-topic at Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do something with Expression trees... There are three ways to do it: creating an expression for each property, an expression for each combination of properties, a single expression tree for each type containing a big `foreach (var property in properties) switch (property) { case "Prop1": target.Prop1 = source.Prop1; break; ... } }` (in this case the `target.Prop1 = source.Prop1` doesn't use reflection).

I'll do the first one that is the simplest.

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static void CopyFrom<T>(this T target, T source, params string[] properties)
    {
        ToolsImpl<T>.CopyFrom(target, source, properties);
    }

    private static class ToolsImpl<T>
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<T, T>> delegates = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<T, T>>();

        public static void CopyFrom(T target, T source, string[] properties)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Action<T, T> del;

                if (!delegates.TryGetValue(property, out del))
                {
                    var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
                    var s2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");

                    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);

                    // The ?. in the source: skip missing properties

                    if (prop == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Expression<Action<T, T>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, T>>(Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(t2, prop), Expression.Property(s2, prop)), t2, s2);
                    del = exp.Compile();
                    delegates.TryAdd(property, del);
                }

                del(target, source);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here there is the code for the "one property == one expression tree". Doing it for "one group of properties == one expression tree" is a little more complex because you would need a comparator for `string[]`. The third one is even more complex (you have the `for`/`foreach` that isn't present in the Expression tree and so must be built, you have the `switch` that is always a pain)

As always with (compiled) Expression trees, the first run is as slow as a dog, and then it becomes faster.

**addendum**

Just out of curiousity, the third way (simulating a `for` cycle + `switch`) :

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static void CopyFrom<T>(this T target, T source, params string[] properties)
    {
        ToolsImpl<T>.CopyTo(source, target, properties);
    }

    private static class ToolsImpl<T>
    {
        public static readonly Action<T, T, string[]> CopyTo;

        static ToolsImpl()
        {
            var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");
            var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            var properties = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]), "properties");

            // indexer of the for cycle
            var i = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "i");

            // case "prop1": target.prop1 = source.prop1
            var cases = typeof(T)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.CanRead && x.CanWrite && x.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                .Select(x => Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(target, x), Expression.Property(source, x)), Expression.Constant(x.Name)));

            // switch properties[i]:
            var sw = Expression.Switch(typeof(void), Expression.ArrayAccess(properties, i), null, null, cases);

            var lblForBegin = Expression.Label(typeof(void), "for begin");
            var lblForCheck = Expression.Label(typeof(void), "for check");

            // we simulate a for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; ++i
            var body = Expression.Block(new[] { i },
                new Expression[]
                {
                    Expression.Assign(i, Expression.Constant(0)), // ix = 0
                    Expression.Goto(lblForCheck), // goto lblForCheck
                    Expression.Label(lblForBegin), // :lblForBegin
                    sw, // switch ()
                    Expression.PreIncrementAssign(i), // ++i
                    Expression.Label(lblForCheck), // :lblForCheck
                    Expression.IfThen(Expression.LessThan(i, Expression.ArrayLength(properties)), Expression.Goto(lblForBegin)), // if ix < properties.Length goto lblForBegin
                });

            var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, T, string[]>>(body, source, target, properties);
            CopyTo = exp.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```